# Prove that $y=a\sin(\frac{x}{a})$ curve is intersecting $x$ axis with angle that is not dependent on $a$.

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Prove that $y=a\sin(\frac{x}{a})$ curve is intersecting $x$ axis with angle that is not dependent on $a$.

$r(t)=(t,a\sin(\frac{t}{a}))$, $r^\prime (t)=(1,\cos(\frac{t}{a}))$

to find angle between curve and $x$ axis we can find angle between $r^\prime(t)$ and $(1,0)$  so $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{a})}}$$ which depends on $a$.

Can you tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$. When $y = 0, \sin \left(\frac{x}{a}\right) = 0, a \ne 0$. So $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not dependent on $a$

Comment: @MathLover So curve in that way is given with natural parametric way? when $|r^\prime (t)| = 1$

Comment: 'intersecting x axis with angle'. So you need to find the point where the intersection happens.

Answer (score 2):

We have to assume $a \neq 0,$ otherwise it is possible that the entire curve is just the $x$-axis itself.

Using your parameterization of the curve, "intersecting $x$ axis" means that

$$ r(t) = \left(t,a\sin\left(\frac ta\right)\right) = (t,0) $$

since the $y$ coordinate on the $x$-axis must be zero.

Therefore $a\sin\left(\frac ta\right) = 0,$ and since we assumed $a \neq 0,$
this implies that $\sin\left(\frac ta\right) = 0.$

Since $\sin\left(\frac ta\right) = 0,$ we know that

$$ \cos^2\left(\frac ta\right) = \ldots $$

and therefore (using the formula you derived)

$$ \cos(\theta) = \ldots . $$

(I left the right-hand side of the last couple of equations for you to complete.)

Answer (score 1):

You have,
$$
y=a\sin(\frac{x}{a})\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(\frac{x}{a})
$$
$y=0$ @ $\frac{x}{a} = (\frac{2n+1}{2})\pi$ where $n$ is an integer. The slope at $y=0$ is
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos((\frac{2n+1}{2})\pi)=\pm 1
$$
which is independent of $a$.

Comment: $\frac{2n+1}{2}?$

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address *Where is the mistake?*, but in general if $f$ is a function and $a \neq 0$, the graph $y = af(x/a)$ is geometrically the graph $y = f(x)$ scaled about the origin by a factor $a$. Since scaling about the origin preserves angles and maps axis intersections to axis intersections, the claim follows at once.